# iOS UITableViewCell horizontally scrolling subviews with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm attempting to build a table view, who's cells contain cards that are horizontally scrolled. I created a simple demo-app and have had success in implementing a version that uses Auto Layout... to a certain extent. One (I believe to be final) issue remains. The vertical sizing of the cards is bugged.

TableView:

```
class MultiCardTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardCell

        //since these cells are re-used, we have to clear out the previous dynamic subviews
        for subView in cell.scrollContentView.subviews { subView.removeFromSuperview() }

        var card = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as CardView
        //Turn this off because subviews of UIScrollView use autoresizing mask by default, which conflict with Auto-Layout constraints
        card.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        cell.scrollContentView.addSubview(card)

        var card2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as CardView
        //Turn this off because subviews of UIScrollView use autoresizing mask by default, which conflict with Auto-Layout constraints
        card2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        cell.scrollContentView.addSubview(card2)

        //Add bottom margin to the last cell (for consistency)
        //Add vertical constraints (standard margins) for each card
        var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[card]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["card": card])
        constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[card2]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["card2": card2])
        //Add horizontal constraints that tie the cards together, and to the super view
        constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[card]-(16)-[card2]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["card": card, "card2": card2])
        //Add horizontal constraint that disambiguates individual card width
        constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[card(==card2)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["card": card, "card2": card2])
        cell.scrollContentView.addConstraints(constraints)

        //Set the scrollview content horizontal size constraint to double the window width (1 window width for each card
        cell.contentWidthConstraint.constant = self.tableView.frame.width * 2

        return cell
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
class CardCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    //A content view directly inside of the scroll view, constrained to super view on all sides, as well as height & width
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollContentView: UIView!
    //A reference to the width constraint for the scrollContentView
    @IBOutlet weak var contentWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

CardView.xib:

[image: CardView Nib File]

Result:

[image: Horizontal Scroll Bug]

The horizontal spacing and sizing is correct, but it appears that the vertical constraints are insufficient or incorrect. I find this hard to believe because they are so simple. Each card has the vertical constraint: `V:|-[card]|`

I've tried adding an explicit height constraint on the cards, similar to the width, but this also doesn't produce correct results: `V:[card(==card2)]`

Result of explicit vertical height constraint:

[image: Horizontal Scroll Bug 2]

I've been wracking my brains for days... What am I missing?

Edit: Added [github source link](https://github.com/albertbori/SideScroller) for the sample project

Comment: For starters, I would suggest you change the pin constraints so they aren't relative to the margin.  You can do this by double-clicking the constraint to bring up the detailed editor, and then deselecting "Relative to Margin" in the Second Item dropdown. It looks like you want it to be 0 with all the sides of the cell, but your constraints appear to be 0 relative to the cell's margin.

Comment: I want the label pinned 0 to the margins. Just in case that was causing an issue, I performed the changes you suggested, and the result was the same, except the the labels ran up to the edge of the colored boxed in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately the issue was a minor typo in my code example above:

```
constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[card2]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["card2": card2])
```

Is overwriting the previous constraints array, and should add to it instead:

```
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[card2]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["card2": card2])
```

Answer (score 1):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

```
var tableviwe:UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableviwe = UITableView(frame: self.view!.bounds)
    self.tableviwe!.delegate = self
    self.tableviwe!.dataSource = self;
    self.tableviwe?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    let angle:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_2);//double angle;
    self.tableviwe?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    self.view?.addSubview(self.tableviwe!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Alert"
    alert.message = NSString(format: "%@ %d", "My hit ", indexPath.row)
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    alert.show()
}
//UITableViewDataSource
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1000
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 200.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "channel")
    cell.textLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%@ %d", "hello my friend", indexPath.row)
    let angle:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_2);// double angle;
    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle)
    return cell
}
```